# Linker error: Qt and libusb-win32

Tags: qt, windows-7, usb, linker-errors, libusb

I try to develop a **Qt GUI** application which will communicate with a board using USB. The library I use is **libusb-win32 v1.2.5.0**.

When I compile the application, the following errors occur:

> ./debug/thread_usb_comm.o: In function `ZN15thread_usb_comm15find_usb_deviceEtt':
>
> thread_usb_comm.cpp:15: undefined reference to 'usb_find_busses'
>     thread_usb_comm.cpp:16: undefined reference to 'usb_find_devices'
>     thread_usb_comm.cpp:18: undefined reference to 'usb_get_busses'
>     thread_usb_comm.cpp:26: undefined reference to 'usb_open'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   mingw32-make[1]: [debug/CALSYS11_calib_app.exe] Error 1
>   mingw32-make: [debug] Error 2

The application code is:

(header file)

```
#ifndef THREAD_USB_COMM_H
#define THREAD_USB_COMM_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QtDebug>
#include "CALSYS11.h"
#include <lusb0_usb.h>

class thread_usb_comm : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    thread_usb_comm();

private:
    bool device_connected;
    usb_dev_handle *p_usb_device;

    bool find_usb_device(
       unsigned short vendor_id,
       unsigned short product_id
    );
};

#endif // THREAD_USB_COMM_H
```

(source file)

```
#include "thread_usb_comm.h"

thread_usb_comm::thread_usb_comm()
{
    device_connected = false;
}

bool thread_usb_comm::find_usb_device(
    unsigned short vendor_id,
    unsigned short product_id
)
{
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();

    for (bus = usb_get_busses(); bus; bus = bus->next)
    {
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next)
        {
            if ((dev->descriptor.idVendor == vendor_id) &&
                (dev->descriptor.idProduct == product_id))
            {
                qDebug ("Device found");
                p_usb_device = usb_open(dev);
                if (0 == p_usb_device)
                {
                    qCritical ("Could not open USB device");
                    return false;
                }
                device_connected = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    qDebug ("Cannot find specified device");
    return false;
}
```

I added the link to the libusb library in the .pro file:

> LIBS += -L\path\to\libusb-win32\lib\gcc -lusb

I develop on **Windows 7**.

Thank you,
Johann

Comment: GCC can be picky about the order of libraries included, you should check the command line that `usb` is included before your `.o` file. Also use `/` instead of `\` in the path; if you want to use `\` you need to escape them `\\`.

Comment: It seems that I can compile the application without errors. I wrote the path to library between quotes and replaced `/` by `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build release instead of debug or the static library is incompatible with compiler version (I faced same issue when I tried to build old static library with MinGW 4.4)

Comment: I tried to compile in release mode but nothing changed. It seems that the format of the path to the lib was the problem.